# associativity in MySQL's from clause

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if this:

```
select *
from tableA natural join tableB,tableC natural join tableD;
```

is equivalent to :

```
select *
from (((tableA natural join tableB),tableC),tableD) natural join tableD;
```

Is the from clause left associative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is equivalent to:

```
select *
from (tableA natural join TableB) cross join
     (tableC natural join TableD)
```

This is based on the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

> Previously, the comma operator (,) and JOIN both had the same
>   precedence, so the join expression t1, t2 JOIN t3 was interpreted as
>   ((t1, t2) JOIN t3). Now JOIN has higher precedence, so the expression
>   is interpreted as (t1, (t2 JOIN t3)). This change affects statements
>   that use an ON clause, because that clause can refer only to columns
>   in the operands of the join, and the change in precedence changes
>   interpretation of what those operands are.